# Why doesn't this Minecraft "/give" command work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/give x_xstolasx_x diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Hellbringer"},Lore:["Guilty."],ench:{[id:"20",lvl:"2"],[id:"16",lvl:"10"],[id:"19",lvl:"2"]}}
```

This is the command I typed in to the command block. In the "Previous Output" section, it is saying

> [19:32:06] Data tag parsing failed: Unbalanced curly brackets {}: {display:Name:"Hellbringer"},Lore:["Guilty."]},ench:{[id:"20",lvl:"2"],[id:"16",lvl:"10"],[id:"19",lvl:"2"]}

Please help me, I need this sword for something I am doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix "unbalanced brackets" in my data tag?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265668/how-can-i-fix-unbalanced-brackets-in-my-data-tag)

Answer (score 4):

A compound tag surrounds its data in curly brackets, while a list tag surrounds its data in square brackets. All tags except for those directly within a list must have a name.

The `ench` tag is a list, yet you have declared it as a compound because it's opened using curly brackets:

```
ench:{[],[],[]}
```

And within those curly brackets you have unnamed lists, which breaks syntax. The `ench` tag is instead a list of compounds:

```
ench:[{},{},{}]
```

You have also declared the `id` and `lvl` tags as strings by using quotation marks, when they are supposed to be numerical (specifically a short; a number between -32,768 and 32,767).

The game will **not** auto-correct any tag-types within item data, so by declaring it as an integer (number between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647) it will remain an integer and not the standard short. The game will still recognize that it's a numerical value even in that case. To declare a short, you append a numerical value with an "s". To declare an integer, you simply use a numerical value.

The `Lore` list must be placed within the `display` compound.

Fixed command, using the correct tag-types for enchantments:

```
/give x_xstolasx_x diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Hellbringer",Lore:["Guilty."]},ench:[{id:20s,lvl:2s},{id:16s,lvl:10s},{id:19s,lvl:2s}]}
```

Alternative, using integers to show that the game will accept it:

```
/give x_xstolasx_x diamond_sword 1 0 {display:{Name:"Hellbringer",Lore:["Guilty."]},ench:[{id:20,lvl:2},{id:16,lvl:10},{id:19,lvl:2}]}
```

It is recommended to declare correct tag-types for the sake of consistency, since enchantments applied through normal means will be shorts.